# Implementing Function Interface using Lambda Expression in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, functional-interface

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Interf {
    fun m1(num: Int)
}

fun main() {
    val a: Interf = { 34 -> println("Hello world !!") }
}
```

Upon compilation getting this error

> Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

Is Kotlin lambda function syntax is bit different from Java Lambda Expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this will not compile in java as well:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface Interf {
    void m1(int num);
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Interf f =  34 -> System.out.println("Hello world !!"); //compilation error here
    }
}
```

With pretty the same error:

```
error: ';' expected
        Interf f =  34 -> System.out.println("Hello world !!");
                      ^
```

To make it correct, name of the lambda parameter should be changed, so that it become a valid java [identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8).

For instance, this will compile:

```java
Interf f =  x -> System.out.println("Hello world !!");
```

Now, returning back to Kotlin. Version 1.4 introduces syntax for [SAM conversions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew14.html#sam-conversions-for-kotlin-interfaces):

```kotlin
fun interface Interf {
    fun m1(num: Int)
}
```

It could be instantiated with:

```kotlin
val a = Interf { println("Hello world !!") }
```

Convention of [implicitly declared `it` parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter) referring to lambda only parameter is preserved here.

Comment: I want to expand on this answer and add that the `reason` why it's not working for Shivam is because he must use an argument e.g. `x` instead of `34` as in `val a: Interf = { x -> println("Hello world !!") }`. This is because he needs to *provide* an argument, not _apply_ an argument!

Comment: Thanks @Stefan. I did the correction in the code and works fine `val a = { num: Int -> println("Hello World") }
    a.invoke(2)`. Here `a.invoke(int)` or `a(int)` both can be used.